# Pronunciation of גפ״ת

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, acronyms

Does גפ״ת (which stands for גמרא, פרש״י, תוספות) have a conventional pronunciation, as do שליט״א ("shlita"), תנ״ך ("tanakh"), etc.?

Comment: I always heard in the velt "gefes"

Comment: It's not Goofootoo?

Comment: HA, first you have to decide if it's Jepeth, Jefeth, Gefet, Gepet, Gefes, or Gepes :) (teimani, Israeli/sephardi, or Ashkenazi)

Comment: Note: "gefes" is also supported by the vocalization [on Wikimilon](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%A4%22%D7%AA).

Comment: I've always heard it pronounced GaPaT - with Patachs.

Comment: I have never heard or seen this abbreviation. Who uses it?

Comment: @WAF Not sure where I saw it used; probably in shu"t. It even has [a Wikipedia article](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%A4%22%D7%AA).

Comment: I'd be leery of using Wikimilon's suggested pronunciation, as there is [another word pronounced the same way](http://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/גפת).

Comment: @TamirEvan Well, that could be why people use the pronunciation "gefes" in the first place...

Comment: ... because it makes them think of [oil cake](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oil_cake) or [pomace](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pomace)?!?

Comment: For what it's worth, [The Concise Oxford Dictionary of World Religions](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O101-Tosafot.html) and "[A Popular Dictionary of Judaism](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=bT6lYgW6gYsC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22gapat%22+tosafot&source=bl&ots=uckiE9lcxX&sig=UCcYAgkGpekcpIx6jS2n69YG5Pc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZpDFUuKKG5KShgeu-4DgCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22gapat%22%20tosafot&f=false)" seem to prefer "_GaPaT_". ...

Comment: ... On the other hand, [Princeton University](http://library.princeton.edu/departments/tsd/katmandu/hebrew/g3.html) and [most transliteraters](https://openlibrary.org/search?q=gefet) of Hebrew books seem to prefer "_gefet_".

Answer (score 1):

In my over 20 year experience in the Yeshiva World (in the Mir and in BMG), גפ"ת in almost never pronounced or used verbally. It's essentially a written expression, not a verbal one. In speech people tend to just say "Gemara Rashi Tosfos", so it's neither an acronym nor an an initialism (see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87381/does-pronouncing-an-initialism-make-it-an-acronym ).